# when android device onopen, run application

Tags: android, package, version, updates, ota

i has android package update application. Sometimes we publish new android version or bug fixing packages. Then users download package and loads package. Also we publish force update and packages was downloaded and loaded. 
It has to communicate with server using broadcast and service.

It works properly if application runs once before. But we need some information about devices to report something. If user does not run application, Service will not work. So app does not work properly.

For this, We need our application runs as soon as android device open. So service will be active. And app works properly.

Update packages comes to our company from different companies. They should change package to start my application as soon as packages loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible starting Android Service and Broadcast when app did not run before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111094/is-it-possible-starting-android-service-and-broadcast-when-app-did-not-run-befor)

Comment: this question was belong to me:). It is different situation. I posted below comment

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can start any services as soon as it has been downloaded, then it's impossible. How can you expect your code to run when the application is never started?

Edit:

All you can do to start the app after the device is booted is setting a receiver with an intent filter in your manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".blablaService"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

You'll also need a `BroadcastReceiver`, so add this class to your source.

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  //MyActivity can be anything which you want to start on bootup...
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

I do not know if this will also work with updating the device, but this is all that is possible. This will popup the App when the device is booted.

I also wonder, is it really required to do this as soon as the device is updated? Couldn't you just check the Android version once the app is booted. Then save this version to the sharedPreferences. Next time you run compare the current version to the one that is stored. If it's not the same, then update you packages. This could be an alternative solution.

Comment: I know this situation. I do not expect my service to run. My problem is that after the android os loaded. For example android 5 to android 6. Also version changing 6.0 to 6.1. We want to get version changing report. But after the version changing app does not start and service does not run. For this, how can i start my app android os loaded. I know this problem was not related to app side. Provider android os package to our company should change their packace? Can i edit this package to start my app after android os loaded.

Comment: I've updated my answer, It is possible to run the app after booting the device, but as stated I'm unsure if the App will run after an update as well. I also added a possible alternative solution

Comment: I use your solution. i will test whether service work after update version all our devices. Many devices work. For this, i was considering of start app after update on android package side. Android package includes updates-script. I will contunie to research from this side.

Comment: Good luck! Keep me informed